# My bottom navigation bar is not changing its index while using will pop scope on its children

Tags: flutter, dart

I want that whenever I press back button of Android while on a page of nav bar, it should change its index to 0, i.e. I should land on the first page of it. But it is not happening. My code -

```
import 'dart:math';

import '../colors.dart';
import '../providers.dart';
import 'home_tab/home_tab_screen.dart';
import 'manage_leads/mange_leads_screen.dart';
import 'profile/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../main.dart';
import '../size_config.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Widget> screens = [
    HomeTabScreen(),
    WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Provider.of<MyAppData>(navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: false)
            .initializePage(0);
        return false;
      },
      child: ManageLeadsScreen(),
    ),
    Container(),
    WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Provider.of<MyAppData>(navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: false)
            .initializePage(0);
        print(Provider.of<MyAppData>(navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: false).pageIndex);
        return false;
      },
      child: ProfileScreen(),
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      Provider.of<MyAppData>(navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: false).initializePage(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBody: true,
      body: screens[Provider.of<MyAppData>(navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: true).pageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 20,
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(-pi / 2, 10))
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            topRight: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            topRight: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(32),
            selectedFontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
            selectedItemColor: primaryOrange,
            unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              size: getProportionateScreenWidth(24),
            ),
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: unselectedItemColor,
                ),
                label: 'Home',
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: primaryOrange,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/manage_leads_icon.svg",
                  color: unselectedItemColor,
                ),
                label: 'Manage Leads',
                activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/manage_leads_icon.svg",
                  color: primaryOrange,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/icon_3.svg",
                  color: unselectedItemColor,
                ),
                label: 'Next',
                activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/icon_3.svg",
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/profile_icon.svg",
                  color: unselectedItemColor,
                ),
                label: 'Home',
                activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/profile_icon.svg",
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: Provider.of<MyAppData>(navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: true).pageIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my initializePage function -

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MyAppData extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pageIndex=0;

  void initializePage(int num) {
    pageIndex = num;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

When I am changing its value using `onTap: _onItemTapped,`, it is working fine, but when I am trying to change it using `WillPopScope`, it's not working. Using `print` statements, I can see that value of `pageIndex` is changing to 0, but my nav bar is not responsive. Only after I hot reload, it goes back to the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example may help you.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => MyAppData(), child: HomeScreen()),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Widget> screens(BuildContext context) => [
        WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            _onItemTapped(0);
            return false;
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.primaries[0],
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Page 0"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            _onItemTapped(0);
            return false;
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.primaries[1],
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Page 1"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            _onItemTapped(0);
            return false;
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.primaries[2],
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Page 2"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            _onItemTapped(0);
            return false;
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.primaries[3],
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Page 3"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    context.read<MyAppData>().initializePage(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBody: true,
      body: screens(context)[context.watch<MyAppData>().pageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            topRight: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            topRight: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconSize: 30,
            selectedFontSize: 20,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
            unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              size: 20,
            ),
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                label: 'page0',
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                label: 'page1',
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                label: 'page2',
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                label: 'page3',
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: context.watch<MyAppData>().pageIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppData extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pageIndex = 0;

  void initializePage(int num) {
    pageIndex = num;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```